# Do Shaving Restrictions Apply to Bearded Women?

Tags: halacha, women, hair

For example, if a woman were to have a beard, would she be permitted to shave it off with a razor or otherwise destroy it, or do these restrictions apply to both men and women?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nope. It does not apply to women.

Source: [Mishnah in Kiddushin (1:7)](http://en.wikisource.org/?curid=337701)

> ‮וכל מצוה בלא תעשה,
>   ‮בין שהזמן גרמה ובין שלא הזמן גרמה,
>   ‮אחד אנשים ואחד נשים, חייבין;
>   ‮חוץ מבל תקיף, ומבל תשחית, ומבל תיטמא למתים.
>
> And every commandment which is a prohibition,
>   whether it is time-dependent or is not time-dependent,
>   both men and women are obligated;
>   except for "You shall not round off [the corners of your head],"
>   "You shall not destroy [the corners of your beard]"
>   and "You shall not become ritually impure for the dead."

Comment: Though paskening halacha from a mishna directly is generally frowned upon. Referencing the Gemara's discussion of this would certainly be preferred...

Answer (score 3):

According to Rabbi Reuven Lauffer at Ohr Somayach (writing in 1999 in response to a question about Omer restrictions), no: prohibitions against removing facial hair do not apply to women.

I've seen the question and answer from the person who asked it. The question asked about Omer restrictions; the response was:

> There is no prohibition for a woman to shave or remove facial or body hair. The prohibition against removing facial or body hair only applies to men.

I don't know what it means when a response doesn't reiterate specifics from the question -- that is, whether he is speaking broadly or only about the Omer. (The answer did not cite sources.)

Comment: It sound from your answer like he was addressing cutting hair during the omer, which is a different set of law/logic than the topic asked.

Comment: @YDK true regardless.

Comment: @HachamGabriel, not true regardless!  Just b/c the custom for aveilus did not include unusual practices, that does not negate the possibility that shaving her face with a razor would be a Torah violation.

Comment: @YDK I meant to say that regardless of when the article is referring to, it is Mutar.

Comment: @HachamGabriel, true as yydl brings.  Comments should be understood in light of what they are  commenting on.

Comment: I've seen the question and answer from the person who asked it.  The question asked about omer restrictions; the response was: "There is no prohibition for a woman to shave or remove facial or body hair. The prohibition against removing facial or body hair only applies to men."  I don't know what it means when a response doesn't reiterate specifics from the question.  (The answer did not cite sources.)