# Is a bat kohen allowed to go to cemetery?

Tags: halacha, women, kohen-priest, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, cemetery-grave

Besides the permitted reasons for male kohen, is a bat kohen allowed to go to cemetery for other reason?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch rules (YD 373:2) that the prohibition of contracting impurity from a corpse does not apply to female descendants of Kohanim. His source is the Mishna in Kiddushin 1:7 which lists 3 biblical prohibitions which do not apply to females: this one, destroying the 5 corners of one's beard, and rounding off the corners of one's hair ("*peyos*").

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7358/759