# How to handle cadavers which are highly likely to be Jewish

Tags: halacha, death, medicine, college-university-school

This question [How to handle cadavers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27782/how-to-handle-cadavers/27786?noredirect=1#comment141896_27786) asked what should be done where a student had to handle cadavers in their medical (dentistry) classes.

A comment took the view that outside of Israel, the majority is not Jewish and it would be highly unlikely for one to have specific knowledge otherwise.   Therefore the comment implied that we need not worry about the possibility of the cadaver being Jewish.

My question is what should the Jewish student do where the class instructor gives specific information that makes it most likely that the cadaver was Jewish.

Eg “and now here is the mouth of the famed Mr Cohen whose oral history has been widely reported in the professional journals.”

Should we say that the principle of [משום איבה](http://www.torahbase.org/?p=102) should apply or should the student absent himself from the class because of [ניתוח המת](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%97_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%AA).

Comment: Not so helpful, but i knew someone named Cohen who's grandfather married a nonjew, then his father converted to Judaism, then he was born as a full-fledged Jew named Cohen who happened to not be a cohen. He married a balaas tshuva started a family. Then he had back surgery and got an infection and died. Sad sad story. But it is possible for a nonjew to have a Jewish name.

Comment: Do we allow nivul hames, mishum eivah? Shouldn't it make more sense to asser these discussions in a public forum, mishum eivah?