# Do women get reward for not shaving their payos and beard

Tags: gentiles, women, mitzvah, reward-punishment

Do woman/non-Jews get a reward for not doing things they are permitted to do, and men / Jews are forbidden to do?

I know that if someone does a mitzvah they are not commanded doing, they get a reward.    
Does this also apply by not doing avairos (sins)?

For example for a woman not to shave her payos, (and if applicable her beard)?
Or for a wife or (in certain cases) daughter of a kohen not to become tomai (impure).

Or for a non-Jew not to have relations with his daughter

Or a non-cohen not to become tomai

Comment: Source that not obligated in these avairos https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foreign_Worship_and_Customs_of_the_Nations.12.3

Comment: I'm not following the premise behind the question. Why is this restricted to women? Do **men**  get rewarded for not doing things that they are permitted to do?

Comment: @DanF the main point is in the second paragraph of the question: it's a comparison to do-it _mitzvos_.

Comment: @DanF becouse of the idea, ano metzuva vose, not commanded but does

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7358/do-shaving-restrictions-apply-to-bearded-women

Comment: @hazoriz a non-cohen not to become tomai is different then the rest of your examples. The Aveira is that a cohen should not become tamei, if hes not a cohen becoming tamei is not what was forbidden. It would be like asking if someone refrains from cooking meat in wine (rather than meat in milk) does he get rewarded? No, because its a different act completely. Same here, A non Cohen who refrains from becoming tamei is not keeping a Cohen from becoming tamei, so no reward.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore Why can't you say such a lomdus in all the examples?

Comment: @Alex By understanding of each aveira, You need to differentiate between when the person is the WHO who is Assur and when it is the WHAT that is assur.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore So who told you that in the tamei case it's the who that is assur but in all the others it's the what that is assur?

Comment: @Alex if you analyze the details of the issur you will see that it is quite obvious. ex. Tumaas Cohen is depicted as an issur kedusha, if theres no kedusha  then he is not doing the aveira.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore see Guide 3:47 where it is explained that the prohibition on kohanim becoming tamei is because kohanim need to be able to enter the Temple.

Comment: Gur Aryeh in vayigash says a person doesn't get reward for negative commands hes not obligated in.

Comment: @Shlomy I heard my Rebbe say it's a machlokes of Maharal and Shlah, but he did not say where.

Comment: @Shlomy I heard my Rebbe say it's a machlokes of Maharal and Shlah, but he did not say where.

Answer (score 1):

Rabeinu yonah in *[Shaarei Teshuvah 3:9](http://%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%95%20%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%9D%20%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%94%20%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%95%20%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95.%20%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%9C%D7%9A%20%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90%20%D7%94%D7%96%D7%94.%20%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%9F%20%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%95%20%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%9D%20%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%94%20%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%91%20%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%20%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%9C%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A8%20%D7%9B%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%94%20%D7%9B%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%90%20%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%20%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%9C%20%D7%9E%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95.%20%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%93%20%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%95%20(%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%9B%D7%99%20%D7%92)%20%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%99%20%D7%94'%20%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%99%20%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%20%D7%96%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%91%D7%90%20%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%20%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%9C%20%D7%9E%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95.%20%D7%92%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%96%D7%94%20%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%93%D7%95%20%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94%20%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%A9%20%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%AA%20%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%20(%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%99)%20%D7%90%D7%AA%20%D7%94'%20%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9A%20%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%90)* writes:

> אמרו רבותינו זכרונם לברכה ישב ולא עבר עבירה נותנין לו שכר כעושה מצוה
>   כגון שבא דבר עבירה לידו וניצול ממנו... **גם השכר הזה עקרו ויסודו מצות
>   עשה שכבש יצרו ביראת אלהים**
>
> Our sages said "If someone sits and does not commit an aveira he is
>   rewarded as in doing a mitzvah". This is when the situation of aveira
>   comes to him and he saves himself from doing it. **This reward is
>   based and founded in the fact that he conquered his evil inclination
>   due to the fear of Hashem**...

Rashi on the Gemara [Kedushin 39b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kiddushin.39b.15?lang=bi) also explains it to mean:

> ישב ולא עבר עבירה דקאמר נוטל עליה שכר בעבירה שבא לידו **וכפה יצרו ולא
>   עבר**
>
> He is rewarded for an aveira which came to him **and he conquered his
>   yetzer [harah]** and did not transgress.

We see from this that reward for refraining from an aveira is only when there is a conquering of the *Yetzer Harah* (evil inclination).

Therefore, when someone refrains from doing an act which he / she is not forbidden to do, This concept of overcoming the *yetzer harah* does not exist, and thus there is no reward.

Comment: +1 does eveyone agree with this Rabeinu Yonah?

Comment: @hazoriz I dont know of anyone who doesn't.

Comment: @hazoriz Rashi does too (edited).

Comment: nice logic but i feel you might be wrong

Comment: Your first link doesn't work.

Comment: How do you know there is no conquering of the Yetzer Harah when not forbidden?

Comment: Is there a reason you left out the term "mitzvas aseh" in your translation of R. Yonah?

Comment: @Alex yetzer harah is for ra if its not ra wheres the yetzer hara?

Comment: @hazoriz "nice logic but i feel you might be wrong" - just a "feeling" or some intelligence involved too?

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore Isn't the whole assumption of the question that even if something is not formally prohibited there might still be something negative about it that someone can voluntarily avoid? If so, I would think that that counts as "ra" for their to be a yetzer hara to sntice you to do it.

Comment: @Alex In the sugya of gadol metzuvah veoseh mimi sheaino metzuva veoseh, tosfos says there is no Yh by Aino metzuvah, yet some schar is given for the maaseh mitzvah, but refraining from aveira is only when there is kvishas hayetzer.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore Does that mean there is no Yetzer Hara whatsoever, or just comparatively? Either way, if it's a necessary premise of your answer it should be edited in.

Comment: @Alex so you think that maybe a non cohen has a YH to become tamei, or a woman has a YH to cut off her sidelocks?? I beg you please use some svara yeshara. [I think I've said all I have to say on the matter].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79469/discussion-between-alex-and-ribbisrabbiandmore).

Comment: @Alex No need to continue in chat. I've said all I have to say on the matter.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore (my feeling are usualy based on intelect, it is just hard for me to find it and to express it) in your opinion is there any reason a non jew should not have relations with his doughter?

Comment: @hazoriz There are lots of other factors which may be considered. Incest may be problematic for other reasons, but not because of the aveira of giluy arayos. His mother, giluy arayos, his daughter, not giluy arayos.